# Java 3d & Texture mappig

Tags: java, textures, java-3d

I am trying to load a 3D scene into java3D . I've tried to load my scene created in Cinema 4D in multiple formats (Obj, wrl, 3ds, x3d) but thus far I haven't been able to transport my textures with it. The most promising up to now is vrml because at least one texture is being integrated. All other formats don't support textures or at least don't load them.

Is there a way to create a 3D scene with multiple materials & textures and export them in a way that I can load them right away in java3d? Is there even such a format supported? (Right now I blame my texture problems with vrml on the poor export of c4d)

How is this done in general? Do I have to apply my textures by hand in java code? This seems kind of odd to me, I have only been able to apply one texture to the whole loded object, since java3d seems to handle everything in my scene as one shape. Do I have to load every object in my scene separately and "reconstruct" the complete scene via code?

Any thoughts on this or links to frameworks that ease the pain are appreciated!

Cheers, Corelgott

Answer (score 0):

Which importer or loader are you using?

Did you try InteractiveMesh's free XModelImporter for X3D files : http://www.java.net/node/706300 . Can you make a test C4D-export (obj and/or x3d) inclusive textures available for download, so I can check it? InteractiveMesh will soon release a new Java 3D OBJ importer.

August

Comment: Hey thx for your reply! I have already tried this with limited success. But I will try it again with other model data and see if I have any luck. Up to now I have performed my tests with the default ObjectFile-Loader, ncsa.j3d.loaders, microcrowd._.max3ds.Loader3DS and a bunch of others. But I think that x3d would be a good option. But before I can test it, I have to figure out how to convert my model (got the file in obj, 3ds and c4d) to x3d. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The ObjectFile-Loader is able to load textures. Check the corresponding '.mtl' file for the tokens 'map_Kd' which provide the path for the (diffuse) texture image. These paths must be relative to the location of the '.obj' file. The supported image formats are: bmp, gif, jpg, png.

Give following conversion tools a try:

- AccuTrans 3D  http://www.micromouse.ca/ , trial period of 30 days
- MeshLab http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/

Also check in the exported '.x3d' files the XML elements  if the paths are relative and correct.

Otherwise wait for the release of InteractiveMesh's ObjShapeImporterJ3D planned for the next week. Or, if possible, provide me a download link or send all files (obj, mtl, 3ds, and textures) to info [at] interactivemesh [dot] com. As an Easter gift I would try to find the issues and convert the files to x3d.

August